# Mysql & PHP - Query doesn't find keywords with accented characters even under "utf8_general_ci" collation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with the "utf8_general_ci" collation containing song names, and many of them are in french, containing accented characters such as "é".

I have implemented a keywords search for these songs, and my query looks like this, where "$keywords" is the user submitted keywords in the form field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT song.id, song.title
FROM song       
WHERE 
(song.title LIKE '%".$keywords."%')
```

So for a song named "Tséveudire", if I search for "tseveudire", the song is found in the query. However, if I search "tséveudire", the song isn't found. I would like the search to be not sensitive to accent and match in both case.

I tried to convert the submitted keywords to UTF-8 in PHP before searching the database, but it didn't work and the keyword was now spelled "tÃ©veudire".

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Beside database your connection has also to be in that collation. Did you set it?

Comment: No, I didn't even know about that. How should I do it?

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ned to set the correct charset.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

etc. If everything still fails, try use `RLIKE` without `%%` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: What's the difference between the charset and the collation?

Comment: The above set the charset for the connection, so data both to and from mysql is in the correct format.

Comment: Man, that was it... I spent at least 6 hours trying to figure out and found nowhere this answer. Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to set  `SET NAMES 'utf8'`, you need to specify the type of character in the selection ... you can use this function

```
function connect_db()
{
$link = mysql_pconnect("host", "user", "pass");
    mysql_select_db("db", $link);

    $query = "SET NAMES 'utf8'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

    return $link;
}

$link=connect_db();
$keywords='tsèveudire';
$query="SELECT DISTINCT song.id, song.title
FROM song       
WHERE 
(song.title LIKE '%$keywords%')";

$result=mysql_query($query,$link);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['title'];
```